# Should my context be a .net type?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

The context for my nonce is:

`` DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.UriStyleMessageFormatter`1[[DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ChannelElements.AuthorizationCode, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServer, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246]]} ``

That doesn't seem right to me.

Should this be something else?
Am I supposed to configure this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [in fact correct](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/03abe2/src/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/Messaging/DataBagFormatterBase.cs#L248). Nothing to do here.

Comment: I did see that in the source, just wasn't sure if I was reading that correctly. Thanks.